# On the definition of tangent vector on a smooth manifold

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $a \in M$. A tangent vector to $M$ at $a$ is a linear map

$$A: C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \mathbb R$$

such that

$$A(fg)=A(f)g(a) + f(a)A(g)$$

I am trying to understand this definition in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$. The tangent plan to the graph of $f$ at point $a$ is

$$ T_a \Gamma_f =\{(x,f(a)+\langle\nabla f(x),(x-a)\rangle) | x \in \mathbb R^n \}$$

So what is $A$ in this context ? A "tangent vector" should be an element of the "tangent plan" no ? So I thought it would be $A(f)=f(a)+\langle\nabla f(x),(x-a)\rangle$ but it does not respect the Leibniz product rule from the definition.

Comment: This is a "derivation at $a$". Given a smooth curve $\gamma : (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\Bbb R^n$ with $\gamma(0)=a$ you get a derivation by defining $f\mapsto \frac d{dt} f(\gamma(t))\lvert_{t=0}$. You can check that this doesn't really depend on $\gamma$ at all, the only thing that matters is the value of $\dot\gamma(0)$, ie the direction of $\gamma$ at $a$. It is a lemma that every derivation is of this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong about the definition of tangent plan to a graph. Here is the actual definition

$$ T_a \Gamma_f =\{(x,f(a)+\langle\nabla f(a),(x-a)\rangle) | x \in \mathbb R^n \}$$

Then for each $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $f \rightarrow \langle\nabla f(a),(x-a)\rangle$ is a tangent vector. So the set of all tangent vectors (tangent space) in $a$ is the set of all directional derivatives in directions $x-a$.

To my understanding, the tangent space obtained following the differential geometry definition is simply "a shift" of $f(a)$ of the definition we see in calculus because we cannot include the $+f(a)$ term as it fails the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Except in calculus courses, the tangent plane of a submanifold is always a vector subspace, so we do not do the affine translation to the point $(a,f(a))$.